# How can I create test result traceability report in Power BI for results in Azure Devops?

Tags: azure-devops, powerbi, reporting, traceability

We are using Azure Devops for requirements and **manual** testing. Looking for a way to use the oData connections to Power BI to create a traceability report that will link Features all the way to latest result of a test that should verify that Feature.

Data is organized such that:
Features = Business Requirements
Stories are linked back to Features as the instructions to the developers on what to build.
Stories are also linked to Test Cases that should verify the story
Test Cases are assigned to Plans and Suites for organization.

In DevOps natively we can pull reports for the results within the Test Plan, but we really want a full traceability report that link the chain together: Features > Stories > Test Cases > Latest result.

Ultimately we want both a tabular traceability matrix report as well as the ability to generate chart off that data.

Getting the lastest results off the Test Points linked back to the Cases is no problem, but we're sort of stuck trying to link back further to the Stories and then the Features.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems you are looking for Work items with direct links sample reports, check this link to see whether it is helpful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/sample-boards-directlinks?view=azure-devops&tabs=powerbi

Comment: Any update to your issue?