# Is there a way to build a requirements test coverage report for manual tests?

Tags: azure-devops

I'm looking for a way to produce reports that trace from the requirements to the test cases (i.e. how many requirements are not `tested by` test cases), as well as tracing from requirements to test cases and latest test run (i.e. getting how many of them were not tested successfully in the latest test run).

I checked the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/test/requirements-traceability?view=azure-devops) but it seems to be suggesting that the available 'out of the box' solutions are only for automated tests. In fact, trying it out on Azure, I seem to only be getting the referenced widgets when I add an arbitrary `Pipeline` (without any `Repository` linked to it) and, even so, I can't seem to get them to reference manual test cases.

Is there a way to get this information in the first place? 'Out of the box' or via some other custom query?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62963857/how-can-i-create-test-result-traceability-report-in-power-bi-for-results-in-azur?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C53.4863) seemed relevant, but then again, the reports proposed seem to be covering different reporting requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/sample-stories-overview?view=azure-devops&tabs=powerbi suggests that the way to get this is by building a Power BI report utilizing the OData feed of the Analytics Services.

At the moment, it seems to be the only way.